# Returning an Object and Scope

Tags: c++, function, return

I was working on a `fraction` class as a CS assignment, and wrote the following code:

```
fraction fraction::add(fraction other) {
    fraction temp;

    /* manipulate temp */

    return temp;
}
```

This worked perfectly, creating a new `fraction` object and then returning it to the calling code.

The question is, *why* did this work? My fraction `temp` should go out of scope when the `add` method returns and thus be destroyed, but it is passed back out to the calling code without so much as an error.

**Why does returning something with local scope cause it to continue to exist after it goes out of scope?**

Comment: Quick answer: It's a misconception.  The local object does go out of scope, but since your function returns a fraction by value, a copy of the local fraction is returned to the caller.

Comment: http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're returning the value of `temp`, not the `temp` object itself. The value gets copied and returned to the calling function, the fact that `temp` then gets destroyed is irrelevant, here.

It's like this:

```
int a;
{
    int b = 5;
    a = b;
}
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

After the closing brace, `b` has gone out of scope, but `a` still contains the value `5`, and is fine. Approximately the same thing is happening for your function call.

If you return a *pointer* to a local object, it's a very different story. Attempts to dereference that pointer will invoke undefined behavior, since you're trying to access an object which no longer exists. But when you're just using the returned value, it doesn't matter whether that object exists or not, because you just have your own copy of the value it used to contain, at that point. (Technically it's still returning by value, here, and the pointer in the calling function will just contain its own copy of the address at which the local object used to reside - you just can't do anything useful with it, because the lifetime of the object that used to reside at that address has ended.)

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now; I didn't know if C++ returned by value or reference, but return by value makes perfect sense.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, a C++ function *can* return a reference, but you have to declare it as such, e.g. `fraction& fraction::add(fraction other)` rather than `fraction fraction::add(fraction other)`. Returning a reference to a local variable that goes out of scope would be bad.

Comment: Exactly. Even then, it is still return by value, but the value is a memory address. So, basically C++ always returns by value. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't continue to exist. You are returning by value `temp` is copied (or moved in C++11) into whatever the return value of the function is assigned to, then `temp` goes out of scope and is destroyed.

Or, on most modern compilers where [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) is implemented, `temp` will actually be the same as the object you're assigning the return value of the function to wich won't have gone out of scope yet.

Looking at a simple example

```
fraction value;
fraction other_value;
fraction returned = value.add(other_value);
```

When `value.add(other_value)` is called it constructs `temp` in the member function's scope, then once it reaches the line `return temp;`, `temp` is copied into `returned` which is in the callers scope. Now the return statement has completed, the function ends, `temp` goes out of scope and is destroyed.

In the case of RVO, `temp` and `returned` are actually the same object and no copy is performed at all.

Comment: >> You are returning by value temp is copied (or moved in C++11) into whatever the return value of the function is assigned to, then temp goes out of scope and is destroyed.

Will temp's destructor be called in this case?